# Expect/TCL and Serial Port interaction

Tags: serial-port, tcl, expect

My apologies if this has been asked, I did search. I'm trying to use expect to script some serial port operations & am quite confused by the spawn_id unexpectedly going away. The msg. is; spawn id exp10 not open. I'll try to keep this short but with enough info for possible answers, the script goes as follows (mix of actual statements/pseudocode):

set comId [openSerial $baud $dev] ($baud is set 115200, $dev is set /dev/ttyUSB0)

In openSerial:

```
set portId [open $dev RDWR]
if 'catch' fconfigure the port for mode(typical), handshake(none), blocking(0), buffering(none) 'error'
return 0
else
spawn -open $portId -noecho
return $spawn_id
```

So far, so good. Back in the main script where I called openSerial I sleep 5 seconds & puts the spawn id, $comId, which shows as exp10. So then I call my test proc without any parameters. Inside it looks like:

```
proc test {} {
expect {
  "string to wait for" { puts "got it"
                         expect "next string to wait for"
                         puts "got it"
                         expect "final string"
                         puts "got it"
                         return }
  timeout { do stuff if timed out }
  }
}
```

I get the first and second expected output, then expect returns spawn_id exp10 not open. Why does it go away in the middle of running? The expect book does not have much on communicating with serial ports so I'm at a loss as of now. If anyone reads this & has an answer, I will appreciate same. In the interim, I'll keep experimenting.

ACE

Comment: Solved it.  Turns out I had two issues, one involving the use of a USB-serial converter, and the other involving the serial port attributes on power up of host ...

Comment: Can you please post more details, sounds interesting.